# Why are my search results not in the same charset as my page encoding?

Tags: utf-8, metadata, search-engine

I am using UTF-8 encoding for an html page.

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
```

In the debugger console, document.characterSet returns "UTF-8".

On the page, I have metadata (keywords, description, title) with a valid UTF-8 character: '®', which is UTF-8: 'c2ae'

The character displays correctly in the view source, and on the page title.

But google search results and bing search results are showing it as 'Ã®'. That is, during the web crawl, it appears to be getting converted to ISO-8859-1 or Western-1252 displaying both bytes: 'c2' and 'ae'.

If I replace the character with `&#174;` => (\u00ae) it shows correctly.

Short of converting my meta data to ISO-8859-1, is there a best practice I should be using for this?

Comment: are you perhaps seeing some cached results? not sure how one validates this, perhaps make a small change e.g.. - ad a time stamp

Comment: We used the google web-admin utility, where you generate a hash and add it to another metadata tag, then request a re-fetch the page. The fresh fetch utility shows the incoming metadata and has the character in it.

Comment: Instead of editing the solution into the question, you should post an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was on the back-end, the data was not being transcoded to UTF-8 properly when read from cache. So, I feel the best practice is to use the native UTF-8 BMP character, with the proper page encoding, and not be required to use html entity values.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pages meta tags and confirm that it is not using this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

For HTML5 Google recommends:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also note this:
[image]

**Note:**

```
<meta charset="">
```

**Another Note:**
Some characters are reserved in HTML. "Html Entities"
These reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities.
e.g.

```
&   ampersand   &amp;   &#38;

®   registered trademark    &reg;   &#174;
```

Comment: In the first sentence I mention my page is encoded as utf-8, this is what i mean. I am using the html5 standard above. And in the console, typing document.characterSet absolutely returns "UTF-8". I will clarify the question, thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer, please post your meta charset and content charset.

Comment: see my note about html entities.